# Why do Font Squirrel's @font-face definitions contain two src declarations?

Tags: css, font-face

In doing some research on the "correct" syntax for using @font-face in a cross-browser friendly way, I came across the following site, which makes a lot of sense:
http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax

However, if you look at any of the @font-face demo code provided by Font Squirrel, the @font-face definitions are as follows:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OswaldLight';
    src: url('/utils/load_demo_font.php?font=1145/Oswald-Light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/utils/load_demo_font.php?font=1145/Oswald-Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/utils/load_demo_font.php?font=1145/Oswald-Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/utils/load_demo_font.php?font=1145/Oswald-Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/utils/load_demo_font.php?font=1145/Oswald-Light-webfont.svg#OswaldLight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Why do the Font Squirrel demo scripts all contain two src declarations? I can't understand this.

Comment: I believe one is a fallback in case browsers fail to understand the others due to the format parameter.

Comment: One interesting thing to note is that I was using CSS Lint the other day, and it throws a warning if you don't use the bulletproof syntax recommended by Fontspring that I linked to above. As such, even though Font Squirrel uses two src declarations, I'm going to stick with just the one, because that's what everyone else does and it makes the most sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an IE9 compatibility mode issue.

For a full explanation, first see: http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax

> How it works
>
> Internet Explorer <9 has a bug in the parser for the src attribute. If you include more than one font format in the src, IE fails to load it and reports a 404 error. The reason is that IE attempts to load as a file everything between the opening parenthesis all the way to the very last closing parenthesis. To deal with that wrong behavior, you merely declare the EOT first and append a single question mark. The question mark fools IE into thinking the rest of the string is a query string and loads just the EOT file.

Then see the follow up article: http://www.fontspring.com/blog/further-hardening-of-the-bulletproof-syntax

> A potential looming problem with the new syntax we introduced earlier this month was raised by Microsoft. The soon-to-be-released IE9 comes with a feature that allows it to render in both IE7 and IE8 Modes. In these two modes, Microsoft 'fixed' the parser bug that affected the actual IE7 and IE8. This fix breaks the @font-face syntax for those compatibility modes.
>   ...
>   This syntax is exactly the same as our previous iteration with the addition of a second 'src:' attribute that specifies the EOT again. We'll leave it up to you to decide if this is necessary.

If you don't care about compatibility view you can clear that first `src` right out.

Comment: No problem. Was looking for the answer, found this question, kept looking, and posted when I found a good explanation. Your question gave me good hints on where to look.

Answer (score 0):

The second one overrides the first if the browser understands the second one, but not the first one. This way you can add compatibility for multiple browser. Browser A uses the first SRC and Browser B, C and D use the second SRC statement.

Comment: But isn't the second format supported by all browsers (including old IE)?

Comment: I don't know which format is supported by which Browser, I just know that such constructs in CSS are used for compatibility reasons.