# CSS, Font-face, Squirrel generator

Tags: css, font-face

I try to understand the generated code via [Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com), here is the output:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'someFont';
    src: url('someFont.eot');
    src: url('someFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('someFont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('someFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('someFont.svg#someFont') format('svg');

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I don't understand why the first `src: url('someFont.eot');` is even required, I do understand the [IE problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050640/how-does-iefix-solve-web-fonts-loading-in-ie6-ie8) so I understand the requirement for: `src: url('someFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),` but what is the reason for the first `src`?

And last thing to note what is the reason for `#someFont` after `someFont.svg` is it needed to prevent some kind of bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src: url('someFont.eot');` is for IE9 compatibility Modes, while `src: url('someFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')` is for IE6 to IE8.

Comment: I understand, but why not just leave IE9 the `src: url('someFont.eot?#iefix'`?

Comment: This is how IE works, even for IE9+ both of these will not work but `woff` will.

Comment: So as far as I understand the first line is for IE9 because it won't understand the `src: url('someFont.eot?#iefix'`, the second line `src: url('someFont.eot?#iefix'` is for IE6-IE8, and the `woff` is for IE9+, am I right?

Comment: `SVG` is a vector re-creation of the font so i guess it requires the font name.

Comment: `woff` is for all modern browsers.

Comment: Yes but was I right with my understanding at above comment?

Comment: I haven't tried to shuffle the positions, will have to test it to confirm. But you have a point.

Comment: One last thing maybe if you can expand a bit about the svg and the vector re-creation, I have no idea at all about vectors, maybe a few words to help me focus here...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687657/why-do-font-squirrels-font-face-definitions-contain-two-src-declarations

Comment: My question is almost identical -.-